Calculating dimentions of impedance-matched pads on PCB in an RF circuit
I am trying to build an RF amplifier based on an existing design. In my first version of PCB I didn't pay attention to solder pads of the RF transistor (BLF6G21) which were quite large on my reference board and I thought it is only for convenience of soldering and in my design I made them smaller. When I received the PCBA it did not work properly and after eliminating everything else I came back to these pads. After making the second version of PCBA with the same large pads as on the original design the circuit did work:

So the problem was that input and output impedance of the transistor (which are not specified in the datasheet) were not matched to impedance of my transmition lines (which are 50 Ohm). I calculated the resulting impedance of these pads as if they were short transmitions lines on their own and it turned out to be close to 22 ohms.

22 ohms seems strange to me, so I assume it was intended to be 25 ohms (50 / 2 ?).
Datasheet for my transistor does not say that its input or output is 50 ohms matched, nor does it specify anything about the impedance.
Overall, after inspecting RF circuits and PCBs on the Internet I see that impedance matched pads is quite a common thing to do, but I never found a guide on how to design them.
So to sum up, my questions are:

How to calculate the required dimensions of the impedance-matched pad purely from transistor datasheet and PCB parameters? (Is it even possible without experimenting?)
Is it correct to treat these pads as short transmitions lines as I did? If so, how to calculate their required impedance?
What parameter to look for in the datasheet for transistor regarding this impedance matching business?
What is the equivalent circuit of these pads?


The original larger pads at input and output look like small capacitors (~0.8pF) in distributed form that are probably needed for narrowband impedance matching at some (unspecified) frequency. No way to tell what and how much you would have to add just by looking at the datasheet. You could try adding some capacitance to the transistor I/O on the PCB that was scrapped and with some trimming make it work as well.

Trace impedance calculations are a bit misplaced here.  More likely, these pads are under 1/4 wave width/length, so can't really be said to be transmission line structures.  What's more, the fact that a relatively narrow trace comes in, then the huge pad spreads out in all directions -- where is the wave going?  Field lines will not be axis-aligned, so the assumptions of microstrip or etc. go out the window.
More accurately, the large pads have some equivalent capacitance, which acts against inductance (or raised Zo) of the connecting traces / leadframe, to create an effective tee LCL network, matching the gate and drain impedances.
Most generally: they will have a distributed capacitance and 2D transmission line character, that isn't easily described by either of these 0 or 1-D equivalents.
You quickly approach the territory not of SPICE (lumped-equivalent i.e. 0-dimensional structures), or transmission lines (1-D structures), but of full 3D field simulation (or at least 2D confined within a planar structure).
In contrast, the connecting traces, and tuning or bias stubs, are likely long and thin enough to treat as transmission lines.  Impedances above or below Zo may be chosen, depending on whether an L- or C-equivalent is needed at that point in the circuit, and of course, what ampacity is needed (not much here, but the really big (100s W) transistors can draw more than a couple amperes, making narrow traces questionable!).
The transistor will be characterized in terms of s-parameters in a specified test jig.  Usually, the layout is given (I don't happen to see this in the datasheet or product page, which makes me question how suitable the part is for design-in approval at all..), and the s-params are measured by a VNA at the ports of that jig.  What the component values or layout are doing within the jig, you don't really know, aside from analyzing backwards from what's measured at the ports.
Product page: https://www.ampleon.com/products/mobile-broadband/0.4-1.0-ghz-transistors/BLF6G21-10G.html
It appears they offer models for Cadence AWR Microwave Office®, which can do simulation, PCB model extraction, etc.  Perhaps the models are more advanced than just s-params (nonlinear harmonic balance, load pull, etc. characteristics? over a wider range than just the specified 2110-2170MHz?), I don't know.  Whether these data are compatible or convertible to work with other RF tools, I don't know either.  But whatever your choice of tools, you will likely want to select one capable of PCB-level analysis.
To summarize:

At least based on what the datasheet shows... you don't.
Not really, but it depends, particularly at harmonic frequencies.
Usually s-params, but the jig must also be known.
Perhaps an LCL lowpass, but mind that any given lumped-equivalent circuit will only be correct over a modest frequency range, and a different circuit likely applies the next octave up, etc.


Thank you for your extensive explanation. So overall, there is no generic rule of thumb to follow when designing these pads... Just to clarify, impedance matching in this context still means that we want to minimize reflections at the "transmition line - transistor gate" interface and this is really the purpose of these pads?

Impedance matching means getting the desired gain and bandwidth, generally while minimizing s11.  The gate generally has a low impedance (it's capacitive over a wide range of frequencies, at least lower ones), so we use intentional mismatch to purposefully manipulate the impedance and gain.
